# Como gerar código indentado?

Tags: php, html

Como imprimir código indentado quando eu dou um `echo` pelo PHP?
digamos que a estrutura está assim:

```
echo 
'<div>'.
    '<table>'.
        '<tr>'.
            '<td>'.
            '</td>'.
        '</tr>'.
    '</table>'.
'</div>';
```

quando eu vou for ver no código fonte da página, o PHP acaba *printando* o resultado em uma linha.

```
<div><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>
```

há como *printa-lo* indentado no código fonte?

Comment: Como está o seu código no PHP?

Comment: atualizei com a modificação

Comment: você não precisa concatenar todas as linhas, deixe apenas a primeira e última aspas e remova os pontos

Comment: O espaço antes do `'` não é identado, deveria ser `'    <table>'.`

Comment: Você verificou se algo na sua aplicação não faz isso por automático?

Comment: @chocolatemontana Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 15):

É bem simples:

```
echo 
"<div>\n".
"    <table>\n".
"        <tr>\n".
"            <td>\n".
"            </td>\n".
"        </tr>\n".
"    </table>\n".
"</div>\n";
```

Tem outras maneiras de fazer isto mas mantive o padrão que você usou. A única modificação é incluir os espaços dentro da *string*. O que está fora não é impresso. Note que para fazer pular linha foi necessário usar o `\n`. E para usar o `\n` teve que usar aspas duplas.

Ou se preferir (eu prefiro):

```
echo 
'<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>';
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/GWud4x). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jrbzqwdg-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/IndentHTML.php).

Comment: Não vejo motivo concatenar todas as linhas @bigown

Comment: Eu também não, mas quem sou eu para definir o estilo de cada um. Se tivesse algo muito problemático eu até sugeriria ele fazer diferente. Eu acho até que deveria fazer mas não é fundamental. Talvez ele tenha um motivo para fazer assim.

Comment: Na verdade @bigown o primeiro caso não vai ficar identado, vai ficar tipo `<div>    <table>        <tr>` tudo na mesma linha, falta um `\n` ou `PHP_EOL`.

Comment: @KaduAmaral é verdade, vou modificar.

Comment: Por que usar `.` no `echo` ao invés de `,`? Concordo, o segundo exemplo é preferível.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pq ele usou :P Na verdade como tive que mudar o jeito dele, poderia ter mudado isto também, mas fica a dica aí. Com a vírgula evitará o custo da concatenação, o que não é importante neste caso específico.

Answer (score 7):

Uma forma muito boa de se imprimir o HTML é utilizando *strings* no formato [*Heredoc*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), que possui a vantagem de não precisar escapar as aspas, exemplo:

```
echo <<<EOT
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="alert('oi');">oi</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
EOT;
```

> **Aviso:**
>   É muito importante verificar que a linha do identificador de fechamento não contenha nenhum outro caracter, exceto, possivelmente um ponto e vírgula (;). O que significa que o identificador não pode ser indentado, e que não pode haver nenhum espaço ou tabulações antes ou depois do ponto e vírgula. [[Leia mais]](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Você também pode fechar as *tags* do PHP e adicionar seu HTML sem problemas, até mesmo em *loops* e condições:

```
<?php
    $var = "Hello World";
?>
<div>
    <table>
    <?php 
        if (!empty($var) ){
            for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" onclick="alert('Oi');"><?php echo $var; ?></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
            } // É essencial fechar as chaves do for
        }     // e do if 
    ?>
    </table>
</div>
<?php 
    /* Continua o código */
?>
```

Comment: O segundo exemplo é a melhor maneira de trabalhar e evitar erros de sintaxe (apesar de as vezes nos perdemos nas `{...}`). +1

Comment: É verdade @GuilhermeNascimento eu também prefiro a segunda, e quando tem muitas chaves e começa a complicar eu gosto de comentar `} // Fecha if ($stmt)` ou algo parecido, mas o [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) sublinha a chave de fechamento quando coloco o cursor na chave de abertura. :D

Comment: Boa ideia, outra pratica é evitar o excesso de ifs ou usar views :) Mas nem vamos falar muito disto por que seria mais um para **dicas** kk. Parabéns!

Answer (score 7):

Se o seu objetivo é só visualizar o código fonte, você pode utilizar o *developer tools* que vem com os navegadores.

No Google Chrome, aperte <kbd>F12</kbd> e será aberta na parte inferior o código indentado corretamente:

[image: Developers Tool]

Agora se você precisa gerar um código já indentado, você precisa deixar isso claro para o PHP, pois os espaços no seu código não são traduzidos para o retorno do `echo`.

Existem várias formas de fazer isso, como pode ver nas diversas respostas.

Outra forma (nada elegante) de fazer isso é usar os caracteres especiais `\t` (tabulação) e `\n` (nova linha):

```
<?php

echo 
    "<div>\n".
    "\t<table>\n".
    "\t\t<tr>\n".
    "\t\t\t<td>\n".
    "\t\t\t</td>\n".
    "\t\t</tr>\n".
    "\t</table>\n".
    "</div>\n";
```

[Veja aqui o resultado](http://3v4l.org/9oKui).

Pessoalmente, eu prefiro usar [*heredocs*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) como apontado pela resposta do @KaduAmaral.

Answer (score 0):

Para intentar textos dentro de uma string você pode usar a combinação de caracters de escape `\t`, o que irá adicionar uma tabulação para cada grupo de `\t`. É o mesmo efeito de digitar a tecla TAB do teclado.

Para adicionar quebras de linha utiliza-se a combinação de caracteres de escape **\n** ou **\r\n** em alguns casos.

Por exemplo, a string abaixo

```
"<div>\n\t<p>\n\t\tIsso é um parágrafo\n\t</p>\n\<\div>"
```

é equivalente ao código abaixo:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Isso é um parágrafo
    </p>
<\div>
```